# Is there byte sized data type in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, types, bitmap, byte, node-red

I am currently trying to use Node to create a bitmap image. I have been using String.fromCharCode() to add bytes however I quickly realized this does not work. For example, if I wanted to create a file containing the hex values FF, it makes sense to me to use the code bellow.

test = String.fromCharCode(255);

When I examine the file it creates 2 bytes instead of one, 0xC3, 0XBF.

Is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Buffer](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v14.x/docs/api/buffer.html) object and then the [readInt8()](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v14.x/docs/api/buffer.html) and [writeInt8()](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v14.x/docs/api/buffer.html#buffer_buf_writeint8_value_offset) function